# Help with monero-integrations/monerophp error

Tags: php

I downloaded the case study from https://github.com/monero-integrations/monerophp. I have also made the necessary arrangements but I am getting an error:

[image]

Comment: In future, please don't post *images* of text. You can easily copy and paste text output into the question.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting stems from the fact the method you are trying to call (`get_connections`) is not an available method when running a restricted daemon.